# algorithm to determine the length of array

Tags: algorithm

describe an algorithm that can determine the length of an array in O(log n).

Comment: Your question is so imperative that makes me feel like doing homework.

Comment: You can find the length of an array in O(1). We need more context to answer this.

Comment: @TheBigO: Please implement `int lengthOfArray(void *p)` in C. Here's how I'll invoke your method: `int *p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 42); int length = lengthOfArray((void *)p); printf("%d\n", length);` If that's too hard, implement `int lengthOfArray(int *p);` and I'll invoke as above without the cast to `void *`.

Comment: @Jason, I've added an answer below, given that new information.

Comment: @TheBigO: Your implementation fails. Google "array pointer decay sizeof" for why.

Comment: well i was able to write an O(n) algorithm for this and it is

Comment: @user597861: Define "array" and state your assumptions.

Comment: int length(int[] A){ int i=0; try { while (true) {A[i]; i++;}} catch (ArrayIndexOutofBounds e) { return i;}}.. but this algorithm is O(n) but i can't think of a way to change it to O(log n)... Thank you

Comment: @user597861: That looks like Java. Why aren't you just using `A.length`?

Comment: ya i know binary search tree would generate an O(log N) time but then the length of the tree would be the length of the array... should i consider sorting it...

Comment: Use your "algorithm" for 0,1,2^1,2^2,... 2^m until the ArrayIndexOutofBounds arises. Then search binary between 2^(m-1) and 2^m. It's O(logn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C style pseudo code:

```
int lengthOfArray(p){
    int j = 1;
    try{
        while(j < Integer.MaxValue){
            p[j]; // Might need to do something more with p[i] 
                  // to test bound.
            j *= 2;
        }
    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBounds e){
    }
    j = searchArrayHelper(p, j/2, j);

    try{
        while(1){
            // This loop is guaranteed to run O(log n) times or less.
            p[j];
            j++;
        }
    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBounds e){
        j--;
    }

    return j;
}

int searchArrayHelper(p, int i, int j){
    try{
        p[j];
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBounds e){
        int mid = (i + j)/2;
        return searchArrayHelper(p, i, mid);
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: It seems in your second function you are returning the first p[j] you find that does not trigger _ArrayIndexOutOfBounds_, but how are you sure p[j+1] will trigger it, and so j is the array length?

Comment: @belisarius, you're right there may be a small bug there. I'll edit the answer to post a quick fix.

Comment: I made the fix, although it feels like a dirty hack. Let me know if you notice any other bugs.

Answer (score 3):

Ok. I'll post the comment I made above as an answer, although your question is rather vague.

Step through i=  1, 2^1 ,2^2, ... 2^m until the *ArrayIndexOutofBounds* error arises.

Then search binary between 2^(m-1) and 2^m until you find the frontier where the error is gone. That's n.

It's O(logn)

**Edit**

This suggestion is based on the snippet you posted as a comment, where it's clear that you are allowed to detect *ArrayIndexOutofBounds*